# Remover aspas ASPAS ao gerar arquivo TXT usando PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Como remover "aspas dupla" no arquivo TXT extraído do mysqli com PHP.

**Função PHP para criar arquivo**

```
// Export data in CSV format
    public function exportCSV(){
        $id = $this->input->get("id");

        // file name
        $filename = 'Avm_inventarios_'.date('d M Y H:i:s').'.txt';
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
        header("Content-Type: application/txt");

        // get data
        $dados_db = $this->Inventarios_model->gerar_txt($id);
        // file creation
        $file = fopen('php://output', 'W');
        $header = array();

        fputcsv($file,$header);

        foreach ($dados_db as $line){
            //print_r($line);
        fputcsv ($file,str_replace('"','',$line),"\n");
            }
        fclose($file);
        exit;
    }
```

banco de dados

[image: Dados do banco]
Arquivo TXT gerado

[image: Arquivo TXT gerado]

Comment: As aspas não estão sendo geradas pelo método `$this->Inventarios_model->gerar_txt($id);`?

Comment: Não. o dado impresso está sem Aspas.

Comment: Você já tentou utilizar o quarto parâmetro como vazio? Assim: `fputcsv($file,str_replace('"','',$line),"\n",'');`

Comment: usando dessa forma tenho o seguinte erro: `Message: fputcsv(): enclosure must be a character`

Também tentei usar dessa forma `fputcsv($file,str_replace('"','',$line),"\n",'');`, porem ele não traz todos os espaços que existe na tabela

_O Arquivo fica assim_ `163836353095 00001` 
_quando deveria ficar assim_  `163836353095         00001`

Comment: Hugo, vc tem acesso ao Banco de dados? Consegue transformar a coluna onde fica `00001` para apenas `1`? Acho que é a opção `ZEROFILL`. Desse modo, o `fputcsv` não vai colocar as aspas. Acho que estamos tentando contornar o problema da variável `$line` mas quem está colocando as aspas é o próprio `fputcsv`.

Answer (score 2):

Para limpar os valores extraídos do array por foreach tente substituir o **str_replace()** por **preg_replace(**) com a seguinte expressão regular:

**'/[^0-9]/'** - Caracteres de 0 à 9

**'/[^0-9 ]/'** - Caracteres de 0 à 9 e espaços em branco

A função irá remover tudo que não estiver de acordo com a expressão regular.

Seu código ficará:

```
// Export data in CSV format
    public function exportCSV(){
        $id = $this->input->get("id");

        // file name
        $filename = 'Avm_inventarios_'.date('d M Y H:i:s').'.txt';
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
        header("Content-Type: application/txt");

        // get data
        $dados_db = $this->Inventarios_model->gerar_txt($id);
        // file creation
        $file = fopen('php://output', 'W');

        foreach ($dados_db as $line){
            fwrite($file, preg_replace('/[^0-9 ]/', '', $line)."\r\n");
        }

        fclose($file);
        exit;
    }
```

Alterei a função **fputcsv()** (pois o objetivo é criar um arquivo sem separadores) para a função **fwrite()**.

Comment: Usando a função **preg_replace()** realmente seria o método mais indicado porque preciso trazer apenas números. porem preciso trazer também espaço antes dos zeros e dessa forma eliminou os espaços vazios também. 

Utilizando a função **str_replace('\"', '', $line)** não gera efeito com as apas duplas. Se fosse para imprimir direto no HTML funcionaria, mas quando gera no TXT vai com aspas.

Comment: E assim: `fputcsv($file, preg_replace('/\"/', '', $line),"\n");` ?

Comment: Assim também fica com aspas 
`163836353095 " 00001"`

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema com o seguinte código

```
fputcsv ($file,$line,"\n","\r");
```

fonte: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fputcsv.php